# How to make view and layout dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a project of an Android e-commerce application. I want to know how can I can make view and layout dynamically for users. I have seen in some e-commerce app that every time when I start the app it shows a different view.

Uptil now I know that we can declare layout and view in XML which is static means it doesn't change. But how can I add layout and views dynamically?

Comment: You seem to be mixing ideas midway through.  It starts off as "How do I create a layout at runtime" in which case the answer is you manually create Views.  Then it goes to "How do I configure an existing View hierarchy with data" which is an entirely different question, and really means you didn't understand much when you started studying Android UIs-  or you're badly trying to ask a 3rd question which is how to get that data in the first place..

Comment: If u visit some  good ecommerce app then u see that sometime after 2-3 visit some views change,i means that perviously there was no recycler view but this time u see it.How i can achieve this

Comment: Either they added it to the View hierarchy, or it was always there but invisible because they didn't have data for it.  I suggest you read up on Views and layouts again, you seem to have missed some key concepts.

Comment: can u explain me little bit what is view hierchy and how they add to it

Comment: Hi @Abhi, did you see my explanation below? If it helps you to understand what you're trying to do, please consider mark my answer as accepted by clicking the left arrow.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

1) You can always make views `VISIBLE`, `GONE` or `INVISIBLE` by using the following method:

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You need to decide when you want to show a view or when you want to hide, based on your application logic. See the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)).

2) You can inflate different layouts in your listview or recyclerview adapters or any other classes you require, based on your application condition. Like following:

```
View view;
if (condition == 1) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_one, parent, false);
} else {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_two, parent, false);
}
```

3) You can define multiple layouts for a single activity/fragment class. Normally the layouts are kept into the **layout** folder. But if you need to you can provide different layouts for different devices or different languages and many more. Suppose if you have a different layout for `hdpi` and `xhdpi` device then you can create different layouts into **layout-hdpi** and **layout-xhdpi** folder. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources) you will find more details about providing alternative resources in Android.